# F# Polymorphism

Tags: .net, f#, polymorphism, records, multimethod

Are there any ways to deal with polymorphism in F# with regards to record types?

Just to give an example, lets say we have two record types of addresses , street address and box address.
I figure that one can deal with them in patternmatching when it comes to behaviour.
but what about referencing, is there any way to reference (not meaning object ref) both types from other records

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, I'd use a discriminated union:

```
type StreetAddress = {. . . }
type BoxAddress = {. . .}

type Address =
  | StreetAddress of StreetAddress
  | BoxAddress of BoxAddress
```

and then you can create and reference `Address` values.

If street and box address share some common data you could put it into a separate `BaseAddress` record type, that is then used inside `StreetAddress` and `BoxAddress`, or used directly by `Address`:

```
type BaseAddress = {. . . }
type StreetAddress = {. . . }
type BoxAddress = {. . .}

type Address =
  | StreetAddress of BaseAddress*StreetAddress
  | BoxAddress of BaseAddress*BoxAddress
```

Answer (score -2):

So I think you want to be able to create something like

```
type A = {aval:int;b:B}
and B = {bval:int;a:A}
```

Now this definition will compile fine, but you will not be able to actually create it as records are constant and you cannot create the required recursive structure.  However, somethin like

```
type A = {aval:int;b:B option}
and B = {bval:int;a:A option}
```

can actually be created and is probably what you want

Comment: You must be thinking of SML - there indeed value recursion is prohibited. In F# (and OCaml) this compiles fine: http://gist.github.com/3098571